# How are question/answer comments ordered?

Tags: discussion, comments

I noticed that comments are differently ordered if there are tons of comments.

What is the ordering? Is it just by upvote?

Answer (score 7):

Comments are always sorted chronologically, however if there's more than a certain amount, then some of the less upvoted comments are hidden and can be revealed using a "Add / show *x* more comments" link.

[image: FHC FTW]

Also, remember that comments from this year don't show a date. To see the full time any comment was posted, hover over the date and a tooltip will show the full date and time.

Comment: As an example, look at [the meme question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) which always has lots of comments.

Comment: yeah so looks like its ordered by date and then votes.

Comment: No, it's ordered by date only.

Comment: but as you can see in popular questions, it only shows ones with high upvotes unless you view all.

Comment: @codecompleting, exatly. That's why I said "however if there's more than a certain amount, then some of the less upvoted comments are hidden and can be revealed using a 'Add / show x more comments' " and posted a freehand circle showing you how to see all the comments. They're *always ordered the same way*, it's just that by default only a certain number are shown and if there's too many, ones with less upvotes are hidden. They're not *ordered* by votes, if they were then the ones with the most votes would be at the top.